# 2-monad and 2-operad of monoidal categories, explicit construction

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory, monads

It is well-known that monoids are algebras for the free monoid monad, and can be seen as well as algebras for the associative operad.

Less known is the categorified statement: for example, monoidal categories are 2-algebras for a [2-monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-monad).

Can someone point me to a place (book, paper, web page) where this is constructed in detail? I understand the idea of the construction, but I would like to see it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In section 4 of "A 2-Categories Companion" by Lack, it is described explicitly (although briefly). https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0702535.pdf

Do you know what he means by "the usual free monoid construction"?